# Why would a process use more memory running on one OS compared to another?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, minecraft, oracle-linux

My process uses more memory when executed on Ubuntu 22.04 than when executed on Oracle Linux 8. Is it something to do with the operating system? Could it be something related to the program (which I find a bit confusing because it's the same binary file being executed)? Etc.

To add some context, the reason I want to understand what is happening is because as a professional software developer who is often tasked with running the software I create in production, it helps to understand how my software will use resources like memory when it's running. I'd like to know how to be efficient with respect to memory used when I write and deploy software.

Details:

The process I am running is the one you get when you download Minecraft (Bedrock Edition) from [the Minecraft website](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock). In the file downloaded, it's called `bedrock_server`, and you're instructed to run it with the command `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server`, so my understanding is that there is at least one dynamically linked file that is loaded from that directory too.

```
# file bedrock_server
bedrock_server: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[xxHash]=51ffa5a7d5d4a199, stripped
```

I was originally using a 1 GB VPS running Oracle Linux 8 to run it. While it's running, `ps` shows the following output:

```
$ ps aux | head -1; ps aux | sort -rnk 4 | head -1
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      650031 10.9 31.0 2585888 297956 ?      Ssl  03:57  82:47 ./bedrock_server
```

I wanted to try another VPS provider because I was experiencing too much CPU steal with this one, and I chose a 1 GB VPS on that provider too. I chose Ubuntu 22.04 for its OS. But this time, Minecraft stopped working after a few minutes when memory ran out. And I noticed when investigating that it appears to use more memory on this VPS:

```
# ps aux | head -1; ps aux | sort -rnk 4 | head -1
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       13620 11.0 60.1 1238576 535844 ?      Rl   15:53   4:39 ./bedrock_server
```

According to "RSS", it appears to be using about 250 MB more memory.

I've tried to leave everything the same for this comparison. The files for Minecraft that are being executed and used as data for the world, server settings, etc were copied over from the first VPS to the second.

So as far as I can see, the only difference between these VPSs are the OS used. One is Oracle Linux 8 and one is Ubuntu 22.04. I'd like to understand why this is causing the difference in memory used. Or, if it's not what's causing it, what is.

Note: I already posted this [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1140826/what-can-cause-a-process-to-use-more-memory-on-one-os-compared-to-another) where it was deemed off topic. [They suggested posting here instead.](https://serverfault.com/questions/1140826/what-can-cause-a-process-to-use-more-memory-on-one-os-compared-to-another?noredirect=1#comment1487924_1140826)

Comment: You could be comparing unreliable data. "*Many of the memory reporting mechanisms for the kernel are inaccurate, due to ...*" See **Inaccuracies of kernel reporting mechanisms** in  https://elinux.org/Runtime_Memory_Measurement

Comment: You sure both instances have SWAP disabled? When it's enabled it's impossible to say how much RAM the process is actually using as some of its image could be swapped out. `valgrind` has a nice way to see RAM allocations - you could give it a try.

Comment: RSS includes memory used by shared libraries, so the reported amount is less accurate. [pmap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap) might help here.